# moment.isoWeekday is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, httpserver

I am using `codesandbox` and the same error keeps coming u: `502: bad gateway`. Looking on the terminal it's apparently because `moment.isoWeekday` is not a function. Why is this?

I've looked on `moment.js` and the way I have put it in my code is apparently correct.

```
var http = require("http");
var moment = require("moment");
moment().format();

function getDates() {
  var start = moment.utc("1st Jan 2019");
  var end = moment.utc("31st December 2019");
  var dates = [];
  var current = start.clone();

  if (current !== moment.isoWeekday(1)) {
    current = moment().add(1, "w");
  }
  while (current.isBefore(end)) {
    current.clone.push(dates);
    current = moment.add(2, "w");
  }

  return dates;
}

http
  .createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
    res.write("day,date", "\n");
    var dates = getDates();
    for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
      res.write(moment.format("dddd, Do MMMM YYYY", dates[i]), "\n");
    }
    res.end();
  })
  .listen(8080);
```

I am doing a task of which I need to output dates. The `isoWeekday` is a part of the code which is supposed to check if the day is not `Monday`, then adds a week onto the variable so it sets to `Monday` the following week.

Comment: you must add `()` after moment like this: `moment().isoWeekday(1)`

Comment: Ohhh ok! Thank you very much didn't notice that. I've now changed that and my expected results have still not appeared. Do you know if anything else is wrong? Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do inside `if` and `while` ?

Comment: for the if statement: the first outputted value is supposedly in 2018 which is not correct. So I check to see` current` as the next `Monday`, a conditional statement.

The while loop is for checking if `current` is before `end`. Then inside the loop I want to push a clone of`current` onto the array `dates`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of mistakes in your code:

1. You forgot `()` after moment in `moment.isoWeekday(1)`
2. The output of `moment.utc("1st Jan 2019")` is null because the format is not recognized by moment, `moment.utc("1st Jan 2019", "Do MMM YYYY")` should work as expected
3. In order to push a clone of `current` onto the array `dates` you must do `dates.push(current.clone());` instead of `current.clone.push(dates);`
4. `moment.format("dddd, Do MMMM YYYY", dates[i])` is incorrect, you must do `dates[i].format("dddd, Do MMMM YYYY")` instead

**Working example:**

```js
function getDates() {
  var start = moment.utc("1st Jan 2019", "Do MMM YYYY");
  var end = moment.utc("31st December 2019", "Do MMM YYYY");
  var dates = [];
  var current = start.clone();

  if (current.isoWeekday() !== 1) {
    //current = current.add(1, "w");
    const nextMonday = 1 + current.isoWeekday() + (7 - current.isoWeekday());
    current.day(nextMonday);
  }

  while (current.isBefore(end)) {
    dates.push(current.clone());
    current = current.add(2, "w");
  }

  return dates;
}

console.log("day, date");
var dates = getDates();
for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
  console.log(dates[i].format("dddd, Do MMMM YYYY"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this has cleared up some confusion I had. However expected results are still not outputting (I'm using `codesandbox`, not sure if this affects it in any way). Could this be because of the line `for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++)`?

Comment: did the example I provided output the expected result for you ?

Comment: Nope, nothing. Link here if you're interested to see: https://codesandbox.io/embed/2pzywqr6pn?fontsize=14

Only the title is outputted

Comment: the code in codesandbox is not the same as I've posted, you did `moment().utc` but the correct is `moment.utc` and  you should use `current.add(2, "w")` instead of  `moment().add(2, "w");`, working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/r4y653x71m

Comment: Oh I see. It is outputting dates now thank you very much. Have I done the new line command wrong? I thought to produce output on new line for each output would be `res.write(dates[i].format("dddd, Do MMMM YYYY), "\n");` ? And also I thought the `if` statement I created would start on a monday with `moment().isoWeekday(1)` ?

Comment: Yes, you should do replace `,` by `+` `res.write(dates[i].format("dddd, Do MMMM YYYY) + "\n");`, and to check if `current` start on a monday you must do `if (current.isoWeekday() !== 1)`, `moment().isoWeekday(1)` output 4 who is the current day (thursday), I've updated the example

Comment: Thanks for all your help, much appreciated!